Serialize class components as direct part of class?
I was wondering if there was a way to serialize and deserialize a class so that a component is treated as part of that class.
public partial class LevelObjectConfig : ObservableObject
{
    [JsonUnnest]
    public Graphics Graphics { get; } = new();
}

I tried googling if there was a existing solution but there didn't seem to be.
I was expecting something like this..
{
  ...
}

instead of something like this..
{

   "graphics" :
   {
      ... 
   }
}


There is nothing built in for this, but you could create a generic JsonConverter<T> that does the opposite of the one from Can I serialize nested properties to my class in one operation with Json.net?.  A custom contract resolver might also work, see How to flatten a referenced object into two json.net properties on the referer?.
